# Proving that a function is analytical without knowing $f$ holomorphic $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ analytic

Tags: analyticity, holomorphic-functions

I know that $$f:\mathbb C^*\to\mathbb C, \\ z\mapsto\frac{1}{2}\Big(z+\frac{1}{z}\Big)$$ is an analytic function since it is holomorphic. Is there any "basic" way to see that this function is analytic without knowing the equivalence of these two terms? Is there a general approach to such a problem?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{C}^*$?

Comment: $\mathbb C - \{0\}$

Comment: Use  $\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{z_0 + z-z_0} = \frac{1}{z_0} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z_0-z}{z_0}}$ to expand $\frac{1}{z}$ in a power-series about $z= z_0 \not= 0$.